# With 16.04 my machine shuts down then restarts when battery level is critically low

Tags: 16.04, power-management, battery

I thought I had set my machine such that it would shutdown when the power was critically low on battery.
In org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power, I have set **use-time-for-policy** to **false** (i.e. no tick in the box) **percentage-critical** to **4**, **percentage-action** to **3**, **critical-battery-action**  to '**shutdown**'.

Indeed when running under 16.04LTS, it does warn when low and warn when critical and it does shutdown at the threshold. The machine then restarts, i.e it behaves as if it had received the command 'reboot' not 'shutdown'. That isn't what I want.

Has anyone else experienced this? If so, can they please tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem a few months ago, I resolved it by installing : `sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools`. I'm not sure why it worked but I forgot to care

Other thing you could try is disabling the Wake-On-Lan feature of your motherboard, if the solution above doesn't do the trick.
To do this, you should get to your BIOS (Usually press F2 or DEL repeatedly while booting to enter BIOS) and search for Wake-On-Lan somewhere, and switch it off completely. It depends on the BIOS you've got so I can't lead you there.

Hope it helps!